# Laravel Passport api test not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying Laravel Passport for the first time. I have installed Passport and made a client. I am using Postman to test. I gave two things in header content type and authorization, but it is redirecting me back to login page. I am trying to get all articles by using this route:

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

I have changed all things in backend from laravel doc

```
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

        Passport::routes();

'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

[image: my postman capture]

Comment: in which file you put this `->middleware('auth:api')` ? web.php or api.php ?

Comment: i put it in web.php

Comment: change all route to api.php instead web.php and try ?

Comment: @MirthfulNahid what error are you getting?

Comment: http://localhost/Laravel_Rest_Api/public/api/articles  i sent request like these

Comment: use `php artisan server` which start server in `http://localhost:8000` and just use this `http://localhost:8000/api/articles`

Comment: What you you written  in `ArticleController@index`, index function  ? return just `json` and try ? or share function code ? it seem working just you put any view instead any response.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `php artisan passport:install` and then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: i know that ... it's not the issue here

Comment: @MirthfulNahid : did you put  route to api.php ? and tried as `/api/route-name` ?

Comment: @MirthfulNahid you are missing space it should be `Bearer yourtoken`

Answer (score 0):

You should add a space after Bearer Word:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Also make sure that you import all necessary classes that relies on passport. The most common classes are:

1. `User` model, import the following class for `HasApiToken` trait.

   `use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;`
2. `AuthServiceProvider`, for `Passport::routes();` in your boot method import the following class.

   `use Laravel\Passport\Passport;`